# Android killing Process using only PS and GREP in shell script

Tags: android, linux, awk, kill, ps

I really need help here...
I am writing a shell script, which starts a process then kills it every 10 seconds then restarts it again.

I understand that using 'ps' command will show all the processes that are running and you can kill it by running 'kill [pid]'.
However, grepping the PID of the process that I am launching is not easy.

I've looked everywhere and for some reason, I cannot use functions like pgrep, awk, xargs, pidof... They are just not found...

I can only think of a way where I have to output the ps file then parse it and grab the PID alone.. but that seems too much...

Can anyone help me? I think I am only limited to using ps and grep only...

I am launching the phone application by running
    am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:XXX-XXX-XXXX 
Then by running 'ps m.android.phone' I can use kill [PID] to stop call the call

I've also tried running commands like 
    pm clear com.android.phone, 
    adb shell am force-stop com.android.phone
but none of them would stop the call...

Please help
Thanks a lot!

Comment: By running  BODY=$(ps m.android.phone),
  echo "${BODY}", it prints the PID and everything for the phone application. Is there a command where I can parse the PID itself and save it to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
am kill package-name
```

or

```
am force-stop package-name
```

replacing package-name by the name of the application you want to kill.

Comment: I've tried using both before... for some reason, none of them actually ends the call...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the process name of the application, then I wrapped together a very quick and dirty script to parse the PID of the process:

```
ps -u $(whoami) | grep firefox | awk '{printf $1}'
```

You should obviously replace *firefox* with your process name of choice.

Please note that I am no expert on the area, but it works on my end.

Comment: `whoami` and `awk` isn't available on Android by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the command `pidof` to get the process id directly, eks:

```
pidof apashe2
```

Comment: `pidof` isn't available on Android by default.

Comment: Like I've mentioned above, I wasnt able to use pgrep, pidof nor awk function to get the PID alone...

Answer (score 0):

following what marcus said:

```
adb shell kill -9 $(adb shell ps | grep firefox | awk '{print $1}')
```